# How to make Partner role mandatory

Tags: partner

I am trying to make the Partner role as mandatory when I select a Partner for a Account..

On the Account standard object we have the related list "Partners"; when you create new Partner; it provide the option to select a Partner (Account) and role in the drop down, but I need to make this role as mandatory, apparently I can leave the role blank..

Has anyone implemented this? or any suggestions to make this work? Thanks..

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007GMFAA2

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you are going to run into is:

1. The Partner Edit page is not currently customizeable (I've linked to an idea for this in the commments, this means you cannot mark the fields as required, nor can you do any standard validation rules against them).
2. Triggers are not allowed on the Partner object (which we could use to inject your own custom validation logic).

Something like the suggestion in the answer to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/how-to-update-account-object-when-related-accountpartner-is-updated-inserted-del) might work however. Instead of having the partner related list, create a custom visualforce page, and direct the users there. This is just to get you started and give you an idea:

```
<apex:page standardController="Partner" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Partner Edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Partner.AccountToId}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Partner.Role}" required="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The major change to get this to work for your purposes is that you will need to pass the Account ID of the page the user is viewing as a parameter to Partner AccountFromId